# Can these two languages be reduced to one another?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions

Given:

$L_1=\left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle :L\left(M\right)\ni w_{0}\right\}$

$L_2=\left\{ \left\langle M\right\rangle :L\left(M\right)=\left\{ w_{0}\right\} \right\}$

I believe I've managed to show that:

- $L_1 \in \mathcal{RE \setminus R} $ since it's easy to construct the acceptor:

```
U(<M>):
  if <M> is an invalid encoding of a TM:
    REJECT
  emulate M(w_0)
  if M accepts:
    ACCEPT
  if M rejects:
    REJECT
```

But according to Rice's Theorem $L_1\notin \mathcal{R}$.

- $L_2 \notin \mathcal{RE}$ since $\overline{H_{TM}}\leq_{m} L_2 $ where $\overline{H_{TM}}$ is the complement of the halting problem, which we know to be unrecognizable. I defined $f( \left\langle M,w\right\rangle) =  \left\langle M^{\prime}\right\rangle$ s.t.:

```
M'(x):
  if x==w_0:
      ACCEPT
  if <M> is an invalid encoding of a TM:
    if x==w_0:
      ACCEPT
    else
      REJECT
  emulate M(w)
  if M halts:
    REJECT
```

These two proof attempts are not related, but they are two parts of the same question - So first I tried showing that $L_2 \leq_{m} L_1 $ which seems intuitively correct but I couldn't work it out. Then I got to think about it and since it's quite difficult to come up with an acceptor for $L_2$ or $\overline{L_2}$ it seems to me more like that $L_2 \notin \mathcal{RE}$.

I'm pretty confident that my proof for $L_1 \in \mathcal{RE \setminus R} $ it correct, but as for $L_2$, I tried so many versions of the pseudocode for $M^\prime$ (including a reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$) and I still can't convince myself that I got it right.

What bothers me the most is that nothing assures me $ \left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in \overline{H_{TM}} \implies  \left\langle M^\prime\right\rangle \in L_2 $: As far as $M^\prime$ concerned, it might also get a valid encoding of $M$ and some $w$ on which it *halts*, but if $x=w_0$, then $M^\prime$ will accept anyways, which contradicts the definition of the reduction. Am I getting something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, and if you're impressed I haven't fully grassped the methodology behind reductions, references to better explainations (other than the classic textbook's examples) would be great as well.

***EDIT:***

Okay, I now understand how to show that some language is unrecognizable via reductions from $\overline{A_{TM}}\notin\mathcal{RE}$ and $A_{TM}\notin co\mathcal{RE}$.

So I tried it with $L_{2}$: $A_{TM}\leq_{m}L_{2}$ seems about right, it resembles Yuval's suggestion in the comments, but I have the same trouble I had earlier convincing myself that the reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ makes sense.

---

### $A_{TM}\leq_{m}L_{2}$

We show $f\left(\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \right)=\left\langle M^{\prime}\right\rangle$  s.t. $M^{\prime}\left(x\right)$:

```
M'(x):
  if x==w_0:
      emulate M(w)
  else:
    LOOP
```

1. $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in A_{TM}\implies
       L\left(M^{\prime}\right)=\left\{ w_0\right\} \implies\left\langle
       M^{\prime}\right\rangle \in L_{2}$
2. $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \notin A_{TM}\implies
           L\left(M^{\prime}\right)=\emptyset\implies\left\langle
           M^{\prime}\right\rangle \notin L_{2}$

Therefore, $A_{TM}\leq_{m}L_{2}$, and since $A_{TM}\notin co\mathcal{RE} \implies L_{2}\notin co\mathcal{RE}$

*In this case, both implications are intuitive and make sense.*

---

### $\overline{A_{TM}}\leq_{m}L_{2}$

We show $f\left(\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \right)=\left\langle M^{\prime}\right\rangle$  s.t. $M^{\prime}\left(x\right)$:

```
M'(x):
  if x!=w_0:
      emulate M(w) 
      if M accepts:
        ACCEPT
  else:
    ACCEPT
```

Thus:

1. $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in\overline{A_{TM}}\implies
       L\left(M^{\prime}\right)=\left\{ w_0\right\} \implies\left\langle
       M^{\prime}\right\rangle \in L_{2}$
2. $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \notin\overline{A_{TM}}\implies
       L\left(M^{\prime}\right)=\overline{\left\{ w_0\right\}
       }\implies\left\langle M^{\prime}\right\rangle \notin L_{2}$

Therefore, $\overline{A_{TM}}\leq_{m}L_{2}$, and since $\overline{A_{TM}}\notin\mathcal{RE} \implies L_{2}\notin\mathcal{RE}$

*In this case, the 2nd implication is really intuitive but the 1st one doesn't seem right.*

Comment: In the case for $L_1$, the machine you made might loop. It doesn't always halt. If $M(w_0)$ enters a loop, then your machine loops also.

Comment: @frabala I am aware of that. But that's why it's in $\mathcal{RE \setminus R}$. I only need to show an acceptor, not a decider. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to reduce $L_1$ to $L_2$: given a Turing machine $M$ and an input $w_0$, construct another Turing machine $M'$ that runs $M$ if the input is $w_0$, and loops on any other input. Then $w_0 \in L(M)$ iff $L(M') = \{w_0\}$.

In contrast, you cannot reduce $L_2$ to $L_1$, since otherwise the halting problem would be co-r.e. Stated differently, if there is a computable reduction from $L_2$ to $L_1$, then the non-halting problem (on empty input, say) is recursively enumerable. Given a machine $M$, construct a machine $M'$ which halts if the input is $0$, and otherwise clears the tape and runs $M$. Then $M$ doesn't halt on the empty input iff $L(M') = \{0\}$. If you could computably reduce $L_2$ to $L_1$, then this would give an r.e. algorithm for deciding whether $M$ doesn't halt on the empty input.

---

The halting problem reduces to both $L_2$ and $\overline{L_2}$. Given a Turing machine $M$ and an input $x$:

1. Construct a Turing machine $M'$ which on input $x$ executes $M$, and otherwise loops. Then $M$ halts on $x$ iff $L(M') = \{x\}$.
2. Construct a Turing machine $M''$ which on input $x$ executes $M$, on input $1x$ halts, and otherwise loops. Then $M$ halts on $x$ iff $L(M'') \neq \{1x\}$.

This shows that $L_2$ is neither r.e. nor co-r.e.

Comment: Thanks! you made things a bit more clear to me on how to construct the code. But the result $L_1 \leq_{m} L_2 $ is still only useful to deduce that $L_2 \notin \mathcal{R} $, and I still can't find a way to show if $L_2 \in \mathcal{RE}\cup co\mathcal{RE} $ or not.

Comment: I suggest you keep trying.

Comment: Do you mean: $M^{\prime\prime}(w_0)$ will emulate $M(w)$, and if $M$ halts, $M^{\prime\prime}$ rejects; $M^{\prime\prime}(1w_0)$ (or any other fixed word which is not $w_0$) accepts; And in any other case, $M^{\prime\prime}$ loops; Is this how $M^{\prime\prime}$ operates?

Comment: I used $1x$ for $w_0$.

Comment: But if $M^{\prime\prime}$ gets $w_0$ as input and halts, without executing $M$, doesn't it mean that $\left\langle M^{\prime\prime}\right\rangle\notin \overline{L_2} $? I don't understand the reasoning. How is skipping the execution of $M$ counts as saying $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle\notin H_{TM} $?

Comment: Do you agree that $M$ halts on $x$ iff $L(M'') \neq \{1x\}$?

Comment: I can see that if $M$ halts on $x$, then $L(M^{\prime\prime})=\left\{ x \right\}$, but if $M$ doesn't halt on $x$, then effectively $L(M^{\prime\prime})=\emptyset$. But $L(M^{\prime\prime})=\emptyset \implies \left\langle  M^{\prime\prime} \right\rangle \notin L_{2}$, and I need to show that  $\left\langle  M^{\prime\prime} \right\rangle \in L_{2}$.

Comment: You might have missed that $M''$ always halts on $1x$.

Comment: I didn't miss it, but I still don't understand. Could you please clarify? I'm having trouble to distinguish the given input $w$ for the nested machine $M$ from the formal argument $x$ for the new machine $M^{\prime\prime}$ in your original answer.

Comment: The variable $x$ is not a formal argument. It is your $w$.

Comment: In that case, it seems like $\left\langle M,w \right\rangle \in H_{TM} \implies L(M^{\prime\prime} = L(M) $, but it doesn't necessarily mean that $L(M) = \overline{L_2}$. I'm trying really hard to understand why if $M$ doesn't halt on $x$ $\implies L(M^{\prime\prime}) = \left\{1x \right\}$. Something in the flow of $M^{\prime\prime}$ doesn't click for me.

Comment: If you can’t understand my construction, perhaps it’s better if you came up with one on your own.

Comment: I think I understand the reasoning now after quietly thinking it through: if $M$ doesn't halt, then $M^{\prime\prime}$ is defined s.t. the **only way** it halts is on $1x$. To put it more formally and explicitly: $\left\langle M,w\right\rangle \in H_{TM} \implies L(M^{\prime\prime})=\left\{x,1x\right\}\neq\left\{1x\right\}  \land \left\langle M,w\right\rangle \notin H_{TM} \implies L(M^{\prime\prime})=\left\{1x\right\}$. Right? I guess I was executing the code differently in my mind...

Comment: Right, that’s the idea.